# Identificar usuarios y mostrar sus perfiles

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un sistema de usuarios que muestre el perfil de cada uno,  solo logro mostrar el mio y el objetivo principal es poder ver los demás perfiles de todos los usuarios registrados, algo similar a facebook, intente hacerlo con sesiones y según la id de la BBDD, pero solo muestra mi información siempre.

```
     public function author(){

  try{

  if($_SESSION['id_user']!=$_SESSION['author']){

         $read_user = $this->BBDD->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?");
         $read_user->execute(array($_SESSION['author']));
         $read_response = $read_user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);       
         $this->BBDD = NULL;
    //header("location:../dashboard.php");
        return $read_response;
    }
    //$this->id_author = $_SESSION['id'];


  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
      die("Error al leer este usuario" . $ex->getCode() . PHP_EOL . " " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getLine());
  }
```

}

este código no me funciona ya que siempre el usuario tiene que hacer una acción para crear la variable author, y lo que realmente busco es que solo muestre su perfil de otros usuarios y no el mio.

Comment: hola @Carlos Estarita, tengo una posible respuesta pero antes de ello tengo una duda, es necesario que uses la variable de sesion?, Estas trabajando con la arquitectura MVC? que framework usas?

Comment: Hola, Daniel, gracias por tu interes, actualmente estoy trabajando en MVC, sin utilizar ningún framework

Comment: Ok, antes de seguir, se supone la sentencia que estas realizando esta en el modelo, entonces te recomiendo que esas validaciones de las variables las uses en el controlador y ahi si envies el valor a el modelo.

Comment: Si, pero al enviar esos valores igual me muestra mi información, lo que realmente busco es que de alguna forma  sepa que id entra, por ejemplo si soy el 6 y quiero ver el 5, me muestre el 5, con su foto y todas esas cosas desde mi login, y cuando lo valido, la pagina siempre muestra mi información

Comment: Con tu `id` en sesión estas identificado para darte permisos o privilegios de acceso a información, y pasando el `id` del perfil que quieres ver por `url` activas la consulta correspondiente y lo muestras de la forma que quieras.

Comment: Te respondo de la manera como yo entiendo tu pregunta y tus respuestas....el problema es que como estas trabajando con tu propio ID de session no puedes enviar tu misma session al modelo y realizar la sentencia con ese valor ya que por tal motivo solamente aparecen tus datos....los mas recomendable es que en tu vista listes en una tabla el select de usuarios sin especificar el valor con el WHERE y ahi si ya puedes utilzar un boton de radio por cada fila de la tabla el cual al seleccionarlo ya tienes ese id y lo puedes enviar al modelo y ya puedes usar la sentencia WHERE....Espero me entiendas

Comment: Claro, de hecho asi estoy trabajando, y todo me ha resultado asi, el problema empezó a originarse cuando por ejemplo yo creo mi perfil, al meterme en otro perfil, al parecer la sesion queda con mi ID, y siempre muestra la mía. Algo similar es por ejemplo a que el id=5 crea un articulo, es logico que al entrar salga Publicado por , salga los datos de el, pero al yo hacerlo, muestra son los mios y no del otro perfil

Comment: Hola, Daniel, te refieres a administrar todos los usuarios desde mi pagina y agregarles seccion a cada uno? Por lo que logre entender te refieres a que mande un Select a todos mis usuarios, y en vez de usar mis sesiones, cada uno muestre su perfil al ingresar con su id no?

Comment: No @Carlos me referia a que te puedes tener una vista con una tabla normal(celdas y columnas) pero tu para llenar esa tabla necesitas obivamente de un backend y ese backend en el modelo puede ser algo simple como esto("select id_usuario,nom_usuario from usuarios) ya aqui tienes el id y el nombre de todos los usuario entonces eso tu lo ves en tu vista...ahi es cuando te digo que en esa tabla pongas unos botones de radio en cada fila...

Comment: y hagas un boton, por ejemplo ver perfil, entonces tu seleccionas el boton de radio y oprimes el boton ver perfil entonces que pasa? que automaticamente ya esast tomando el id del usuario que quieres ver y ahi es donde usas la sentencia que sera : traigaime toda la informacion que necesito WHERE id = 7...ahora si me entiendes?

Comment: Gracias!!! ya entendi!! podria ser asi, hago una pagina donde muestre todos los usuarios, o sea todos los perfiles como facebook donde sale el buscador, le agrego su paginacion, etc y al entrar en cada perfil la tabla ya sabra a quien mostrarme, puede ser asi, a eso te refieres?

Comment: exacto, por lo menos en mi caso cuando se me presentan ese tipo de cosas hago tal cual te dije, yo pincho en un botón y le doy ver por ejemplo ver y me muestra en un popup lo que necesito y ya esta...pero ps ya me has entendido la idea...Saludos.

Comment: Exacto, lo que me dices podria moldearlo por ejemplo necesito que alguien postee algo, y al postearlo muestre, publicado por, tal persona y su foto, lo que podria hacer es combinar ambas querys, y unificarlas

Comment: si, por medio de un INNER JOIN

Comment: Gracias genio!!, la solución la tenia ahí en las narices y no la veia, gracias por tu respuesta Daniel, disculpa si demore en entender jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues entonces, accede a tu base de datos, accede a la tabla que contiene los usuarios registrados, alli te aparacera una lista con los usuarios registrados, alli te mostrara todos los datos de cada usuario, pero si quieres algo mas avanzado y personalizado, busca en internet algunas tablas que ya este hechas solo para descargar y editas los archivos de manera que hagan que se conecten a tu base de datos de manera efectiva

Comment: Exacto, ese es el propósito, yo puedo acceder a esa tabla, pero al hacer lo que me inidicas la tabla me da mis datos, y lo que busco es que puedan interactuar todos los usuarios es decir, el id 5 vea el perfil del id:7 de mi tabla, y mi problema radica en que siempre muestra solo el perfil del usuario actual

Comment: Si, se de que me hablas, pero no, mira cuando entras a la base de datos, tienes acceso a ver las tablas completas, te mostrara todos los usuarios que se han registrado, ya que no hay limitacion para el administrador, excepto cuando no tiene los permisos